# upper case all characters in browser autofill dropdown

Tags: html, css

In the pop up drop down which opens up when typing starts on a html form. How can I capitalise all characters in each line of the list shown which reveals the previously entered values?

The following only make the first letter upper case.

```css
input#plate {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    text-transform: none;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    text-transform: none;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    text-transform: none;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="plate" autocapitalize="characters" placeholder="Enter Plate">
```

**edit**
Changing the `none` in the css to `uppercase` did not do it either.

Comment: Are you referring to situations like when you start typing in an email field and it suggests an email address you entered before? If that's the case, that value should not be effected by the placeholder styles. It's dependent on how the user entered it before.

Comment: I echo @alexbea's comment—I have a feeling that you want to make the values uppercase and not just making them *appear* to be uppercase. In one way or another, there is no way to modify the appearance of the input suggestion from the browser—its styles and appearance are vendor specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autofill drop-down list is a part of the browser user interface itself, so unfortunately its appearance can’t be modified. In this respect, it’s like a context menu.

The `::placeholder` pseudo-element can be used to style a placeholder text, like the one in the Stack Overflow’s search field (*Search Q&A*) in the page header.